# Why do I get duplicate Joins in querydsl

Tags: java, spring, jpa, join, querydsl

```java
// 1
jpaQueryFactory
                .selectFrom(image)
                .leftJoin(clientInfo)
                                .on(image.clientInfo.id.eq(clientInfo.id))
                .leftJoin(task)
                                .on(image.id.eq(task.imageId))
                .where(image.clientInfo.key.eq("auth"))

// 2
jpaQueryFactory
                .selectFrom(image)
                .leftJoin(clientInfo)
                                .on(image.clientInfo.id.eq(clientInfo.id))
                .leftJoin(task)
                                .on(image.id.eq(task.imageId))
                .where(clientInfo.key.eq("auth"))
```

```java
// 1
Hibernate: 
    select *
    from
        image t1_0 
    join
        client c2_0 
            on c2_0.id=t1_0.client_id 
    left join
        client c1_0 
            on t1_0.client_id=c1_0.id 
    left join
        task t2_0 
            on t1_0.id=t2_0.text_to_image_id 
    where
        c2_0.key=? 
// 2
Hibernate: 
    select *
    from
        image t1_0 
    left join
        client c1_0 
            on t1_0.client_id=c1_0.id 
    left join
        task t2_0 
            on t1_0.id=t2_0.text_to_image_id 
    where
        c1_0.key=?
```

The second code explains why duplicate joins do not occur,
Why does the first code cause duplicate joins?

If I make a reference, will an additional join occur?
Is this the difference between the on clause and the where clause?